# updating Searched Information

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with the following information “B” Emp. Name, “C” Position, Location “D”, Salary “E” in which I want to create a find cmd button and other cmd button for updating information. so I used the following codes for find and it works very well but the updating commend work wrongly, when I search for specific information, it shows the required information but when making the change in the form and press update, it change the first row of the table not the search row. so please your assistance.

```
Private Sub Search_Click()
Dim FindRow
Dim cRow As String
On Error Resume Next
cRow = Me.txtSearch.Value
'find the name of the employee written on the search box in column B
Set FindRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B").Find(what:=cRow, LookIn:=xlValues)
'add the values to the userform
 Me.txtname.Value = FindRow
 Me.txtposition.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 1)
 Me.txtlocation.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 2)
 Me.txtbasicsalary.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 3)
End Sub

Sub UpdateInfo_Click()
Dim FindRow
Dim fname As String
Dim lname As String
FindRow = 2
fname = txtname.Text
Cells(FindRow, 2).Value = fname
lname = txtposition.Text
Cells(FindRow, 3).Value = lname
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to `Dim FindRow As Range` outside the button's sub, but at the `User_Form` module level, so all `Sub`s within the user_form will read and modify the same variable.

Second, you need to make sure `Find` was successful retrieving a match in "Sheet1", by `If Not FindRow Is Nothing Then`.

Third, in your `UpdateInfo_Click` sub, make sure you ran `Search_Click` before, and that `FindRow` was able to find a match in Column B, then you can modify the values using `FindRow.Row`.

Last, keep using `Sheets("Sheet1")` before your `Cells` to fully qualify it, just like you did in `Set FindRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B").Find(what:=cRow, LookIn:=xlValues)`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Dim FindRow As Range

Private Sub Search_Click()

Dim cRow As String

On Error Resume Next
cRow = Me.txtSearch.Value
'find the name of the employee written on the search box in column B
Set FindRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B").Find(what:=cRow, LookIn:=xlValues)

If Not FindRow Is Nothing Then '<-- successful find
    'add the values to the userform
     Me.txtname.Value = FindRow.Value
     Me.txtposition.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 1).Value
     Me.txtlocation.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 2).Value
     Me.txtbasicsalary.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 3).Value
End If

End Sub

'======================================================================

Sub UpdateInfo_Click()

Dim fname As String
Dim lname As String

fname = Me.txtname.Text
lname = Me.txtposition.Text

If Not FindRow Is Nothing Then '<-- check if there was a successful find in the "Search" sub
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(FindRow.Row, 2).Value = fname
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(FindRow.Row, 3).Value = lname

    Set FindRow = Nothing '<-- clear after use
End If

End Sub
```

---

How to mark as "ANSWER" , see image below:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks Shai, it works very well now, I highly appreciate it.

Comment: @NabilAmer you're welcome, please mark as "answer" , by clicking on the **V** next to my answer (it should turn green)

Comment: hi Shai, please be informed that I search every part of this page even in the vote tab but found nothing. maybe there is a problem with this page!?